# Spring ServletUriComponentsBuilder and square brackets in query params

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to use Spring's `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` to create paging `next` and `prev` links from the current request.

The problem I'm having is that the `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()` is not unencoding percent-encoded values like:

`http://example.com/articles?page%5Bnumber%5D=2`

The problem is uses *could* have called the page with unencoded square brackets like `http://example.com/articles?page[number]=2` without any problems.

Spring Data is accepting both variants (both unencoded square brackets and encoded square brackets) in it's pageable argument resolver.
This to the fact that under water the Coyote web request get parameter is used which contains the unencoded param names.

Also Spring's `@RequestParam("page[number]")` accepts without any problem the encoded request like `http://example.com/articles?page%5Bnumber%5D=2`.

From the server side I always want to return percent encoded url's as per RFC 3986.

But there does not seem a way to this as the `UriComponents` query params might contain both encoded en uncoded names. Because to that, if I would call `encode()` on the builder the already encoded query params get encoded another time, but if would contain unencoded names `toURI()` will fail as an unencoded `[` is not allowed.

Note that the url's might contain multiple query params besides paging, e.g. for filtering.

A request could come in like:

`http://example.com/articles?filter[category]=food`

And would return a response with a encoded `next` link like:

`http://example.com/articles?page%5Bnumber%5D=2&filter%5Bcategory%5D=food`

My workaround it to ignore `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` and simply get the request url and do so custom regexp replacing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question and you also found a workaround. But did you try to use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`'s `build()` method?
Some kind of the following:

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().build().toUriString();
```

I had some issues when handling JSON Strings and this helped.